# multi class prediction metric

Tags: probability, predictive-models, accuracy

I would like a method that generalized metrics for multiclass. Including imbalanced classes.
This metric should be all against all.
I thought of Generalizing the Mathew's coefficient but not in the Cramer V fashion

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What's wrong with crossentropy loss?

Comment: it does not measure the goodness of the fit. It is only a proxy

Comment: In what way is it only a proxy?

Comment: it is not a testing the goodness of the fit but the similarity of the classes
it is not equivalent to F1 in general case

Comment: How does $F1$ test the goodness of fit?